# JS run a data-count in percentage, not in numbers

Tags: javascript

i have this code and i want it to count in percentage, not in numbers how it is showed in the next code, how can i do it?

if someone could help me please, i'm not very good at Javascript

```
    /* Counter - CountTo */
var a = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('#counter').length) { // checking if CountTo section exists in the page, if not it will not run the script and avoid errors   
        var oTop = $('#counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
        if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
        $('.counter-value').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
            countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
            $({
            countNum: $this.text()
            }).animate({
                countNum: countTo
            },
            {
                duration: 2000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function() {
                $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
                },
                complete: function() {
                $this.text(this.countNum);
                //alert('finished');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $this.text(commaSeparateNumber(this.countNum));
                    //alert('finished');
                  }
            });
        });
        a = 1;
        }
        
    }
});

<div class="cell">
   <div class="counter-value number-count" data-count="97%">1%</div>
      <p class="counter-info p-small">Percentage</p>
</div>
```

Comment: to use Percentage just divide the number by the max value and multiply by 100

Comment: I need that the number shows as a percentage (with the % sign) not a formula

Comment: so add +"%" to it...   and what is the number , what is the max value it can be and what field you to change?

Comment: the "%" is added in the code, you can see the HTML part, in the [data-count="97%], but when you run it, it shows as number, not with the "%" sign. i just want to add a "%" sign to the right of the number

Comment: I assume you want `$this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum)+"%");`

Comment: yeah thanks! that worked, but when the count finish, the % sign dissapear, how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add % after the text.

```
$this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum)+"%"); 
$this.text(this.countNum+"%");
$this.text(commaSeparateNumber(this.countNum)+"%");
```

or use css `::after` (better way in my opinion because you can control the '`%`'  style):

```
.counter-value::after{
    content:'%';
}
```

And if your counter isn't percentaged - just divide it by the max value it can be and multiply by 100

Comment: Thanks! this worked, i used the CSS, was a better option